# Calculation with approximate digits in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, significant-digits

I have a problem calculating with significant figures in Wolfram Mathematica.
Let me explain better.

I have

```
f[a_, b_] = a b Sin[25]
```

and

```
f[92.0 , 9.81] =381.421
```

However, I would first like to approximate the result of the product between a and b to three significant digits and then multiply it by `Sin [25]`. In short, I would like a function like this

```
f1[a_, b_] = NumberForm[a b, {3, 0}] Sin[25]
```

But if I evaluate

```
f1[92,0 , 9.81]
```

I get

```
f1[92,0 , 9.81]= 903.Sin[25]
```

instead of `381.62`.

How should I modify `f1[a_, b_]` to get `f1[92,0 , 9.81]=381.62` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Round` to round to 3 significant digits in your specific case.  Then the result is an integer, so `Sin[25]` does not convert to a real number (a floating point number).  However this can be forced with [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html).

Also `Sin` assumes radian input unless the input is specified as degree.

Note use of [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) for the function definition.

```
f[a_, b_] := N[Round[a b] Sin[25 Degree]]

f[92.0, 9.81]
```

> 381.624

For 3 significant digits on `a b` in general you can use

```
f[a_, b_] := N[Round[a b, 10^(-3 + Floor[Log10[Abs[a b]]] + 1)] Sin[25 Degree]]
```

E.g. rounding `a b`

```
a = 1.2345;
b = 5.4321;
N[Round[a b, 10^(-3 + Floor[Log10[Abs[a b]]] + 1)]]
```

> 6.71